# Java dynamic object storage in HashSet

Tags: java

i need to store ambiguous Objects like this (each has its own class):

```
ObjectA 
ObjectB
ObjectC
```

The HashSet created looks like:

```
public static HashSet<Object> objects = new HashSet<Object>();
```

then i place the objects in one at a time:

```
object.add(new ObjectA());
```

However here's the problem, if later on i need to retrieve certain objects like this by iterating:

```
for(Object obj : objects){
    if(obj instanceof ObjectA){
        // print that the object is A
    }
}
```

Nothing ever happens, and even if i know the only object in there is ObjectA i get this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashSet$Node cannot be cast to ***.*****.******.objects.ObjectA
```

What is causing this? Why are the Objects all of a sudden not an instance of themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem has nothing to do with generics. This problem as to do with Java not knowing what kind of `Object` you want when you are doing `for (Object obj : objects) { ... }`.

### Explanation

I believe you typed the error message wrong; I think it should be this (emphasis added by me):

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Hash***Map***$Node cannot be cast to ***.*****.******.objects.ObjectA

The reason for the error is that a Java `HashSet` is backed by a Java `HashMap` with `null` for values. Internally a `HashMap` uses the `HashMap$Node` class to store it's elements:

```
// from the Java source code for HashMap
/**
 * Basic hash bin node, used for most entries.  (See below for
 * TreeNode subclass, and in LinkedHashMap for its Entry subclass.)
 */
// Inner class of HashMap - inner classes are always named like OuterClass$InnerClass in bytecode
static class Node<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> { ... }
```

Remember that because all classes in Java eventually derive from `Object`, so when you iterate a `HashSet` like this...

```
for (Object obj : objects){
    if(obj instanceof ObjectA){
        // print that the object is A
    }
}
```

... `Object obj` could be literally *anything*. Java ***apparently*** finds the first match to an `Object` that it can find and decides that the internal `HashMap$Node` class that stores elements would be a suitable match for an `Object` (because it is). It then proceeds to iterate over and give you `HashMap$Node`'s instead of the actual values that you want. *That* is probably the cause of your `ClassCastException` - you got `HashMap$Node` instead of the `Objects` you wanted.

### Solution

Since all objects derive from, well *`Object`*, the only way to tell Java that you want actual values would be using the old-fashioned `Iterator<E>` method before the days of the enhanced-`for` (this will go in place of your current for loop):

```
Iterator<Object> iter = objects.iterator();
Object obj;
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    obj = iter.next();
    if (obj instanceof ObjectA) {
        // ... do stuff ...
    }
}
```

This should work like you want because it is guaranteed to give you only your values because it is implemented like this in `HashSet`:

```
// from the Java source code for HashSet
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return map.keySet().iterator(); // only get the keys from the underlying HashMap, i.e. the values.
}
```

Comment: I just checked error again and yes it was HashMap not HashSet

Comment: @ThatGuy343 man... never copy an error by hand, give out the exact message.

Comment: @dudeprgm on which JDK are you basing your answer ? JDK8 indeed used `Node`, but I can find it on JDK7, which the user said he's using. Also, I would have liked that you reproduce the exception

Comment: `HashMap` is not `Iterable`, so `objects` is definitely not a `HashMap`. If it's a `HashSet` and it contains `HashMap$Node` elements, fine, but we still haven't seen a cast that could cause that error. The enhanced for loop is effectively what you posted. Both are equivalent.

Comment: @Dici I'm using JDK8, but let my check JDK7

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis `HashSet` is backed by `HashMap`. Yes, I agree that there is no cast that could have caused the error from the source code that the OP gave, but I suspect that there is one in the full code.

Comment: It doesn't matter what it's backed by. `for (Object obj : objects)` would not compile if `objects` was a `HashMap`.

Comment: You both are right but not talking about the same thing. dudeprgm found why the message included a reference to a mystery class `Node` that we could not find in `HashSet` and that was apparently introduced only in JDK8, that's why he mentioned it. As far as I'm concerned, I think the question is completely unclear (wrong error message, missing relevant code) and that the OP does not make any effort to make it answerable.

Comment: @dici The assumptions made in this answer are based on wrong information. The `Node` would only show up with something like [pbabcdefp](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27750404/438154) has shown, where you get the `Map`'s `entrySet`, which OPs hasn't shown. Furthermore, the proposed Solution doesn't fix anything. It is completely equivalent to the `for` loop shown in the question.

Comment: There is no explanation. OP has not provided the required details to answer this. The question should be closed until such details are provided.

Comment: @Dici I don't have the JDK7 source on my computer right now, but JDK6 does not have `HashMap$Node`. If it is not in JDK7 as you say, OP might have been mistaken.

Comment: @dudeprgm I was basing on that to make this assumption : http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis This is the best explanation I can give based on the details given. Seeing as this is accepted I assume that OP has used the Solution and found it to work in his code, showing that it **_did_**, in fact, fix something. Based on the details given, and that my answer apparently helped, I can only assume that either OP had an incorrect usage of the enhanced-for or `HashSet` (likely), or there is a bug in Java (unlikely). If my answer did not help the OP, I highly encourage the OP to un-accept my answer and add more details.

Comment: You have to understand that Stackoverflow isn't about the OP. It's about the question (and about the answer). **Currently**, the details in the question are contradictory. The exception shown cannot occur in the code shown. You've identified that there is a `Node` class. Great, but that is not the issue. The issue an incorrect cast. Your bold solution does not present a solution to the (inexistent) cast. The `Iterator` solution you propose is 100% equivalent to the enhanced `for `loop. They would both give the same behavior.

Comment: Again, remember that SO is about quality and being a repository of knowledge for others. There is currently nothing relating the error message to the code. This won't be helpful to anyone else. Don't encourage such post by posting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

We'll never know what the OP wrote, but here's how you could plausibly end up getting the error message reported while doing something similar to what was described in the question. (The OP has confirmed that the error message referred to HashMap$Node, not HashSet$Node). It's all supposition. **If you like this, upvote dudeprgm's answer, not mine**.

```
public class Main {

    static class ObjectA {}

    static class ObjectB {}

    static class ObjectC {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Object, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(new ObjectA(), 1);
        map.put(new ObjectB(), 2);
        map.put(new ObjectC(), 3);
        // objects will contain ObjectA, ObjectB and ObjectC instances. 
        Set<Object> objects = new HashSet<Object>();
        objects.add(new ObjectA());
        objects.add(new ObjectB());
        objects.addAll(map.entrySet()); // Here we mean to do map.keySet().
        for (Object obj : objects) {
            if (obj instanceof ObjectB) {
                ObjectB objB = (ObjectB) obj;
                // Do something with objB
            } else if (obj instanceof ObjectC) {
                ObjectC objC = (ObjectC) obj;
                // Do something with objC
            } else {
                ObjectA objA = (ObjectA) obj;
                // Do something with objA
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's nice to having reproduced the exception, however we cannot be sure taht this code is equivalent to the OP's. You are casting an `Entry` to a `String`, no wonder why it does not work, but in the OP's snippet there is no such thing

Comment: @Dici I know. We can't be sure of anything. The OP gave the wrong exception and code that won't compile. I just wanted to see if I could reproduce the exception. We'll probably never know what the OP wrote!

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately. Thanks for having reproduced it anyway

Comment: Thanks for adding a example that reproduces the problem :). The error shouldn't happen with a `HashSet` though, but as you said, we'll never know what the OP actually wrote. +1

Comment: @dudeprgm Thank you. I've been puzzling over this for ages. I think what I've written is quite plausible.